# Import of classes to be used in Spring XML and SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm happily using SpEL into XML files to configure Spring Beans.

However, I'd like to shorten expressions like this:

```
<constructor-arg value = "#{ T(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils).toString ( new java.io.FileReader ( './test.dat' ) ) }" />
```

Is there a way to static import methods like `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString()` (or at least the `IOUtils` class), as it is possible in Java? Is this possible in regular XML values as well (e.g., in `<bean class = "..." >`)?.

**UPDATE**

The [Artem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636399/529286) below is a good one, in particular, the approach of defining a new bean that instantiates the utility class. Maybe it's worth to highlight that Spring allows you to do so even when IOUtils has a private constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called [SpEL-function](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions):

```
public class SpELFunctionBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.setBeanExpressionResolver(new StandardBeanExpressionResolver() {

            @Override
            protected void customizeEvaluationContext(StandardEvaluationContext evalContext) {
                evalContext.registerFunction("ioToString",
                        IOUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod("toString", new Class[] { FileReader.class }));
            }

        });
    }

}
```

And register this as a bean in your context.

In the end your expression will look like:

```
"#{ #ioToString( new java.io.FileReader ( './test.dat' ) ) }"
```

**UPDATE**

Another solution is like common bean with those utility methods:

```
<bean id="myUtility" class="...">
...

"#{ myUtility.toString('./test.dat') }"
```

and perform all the hard logic already in that class.

Comment: Uhm, thank you, although it seems quite ugly. I guess I can register ioToString ( String ) and instantiate a file reader inside the method.

Comment: Well, it's not much uglier than Java style with method, all the import hell, proper casts etc. If you don't like such an approach, would be better to stay with an original `T` operation solution.

Comment: Import hell that is dealt with by Eclipse. Here I should register every function I need, declaring stuff on top of the XML would be another story.

Comment: OK. You can have a top level bean and call its utility methods from those expressions.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Are you sure? IOUtils.toString() is a static method. I know I could code a class having runtime methods that wrap static ones, but I'm checking if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: No, there is no simpler solution. You can make that bean from the `IOUtils`. Spring is possible to creat a bean from XML config even if it has `private` Ctor. And yes, instances can call their static methods. Just try it in regular Java! We spent with you have so much time already that the simplest solution to follow with Spring docs and go ahead with other code. If you think you have so many similar expressions in your config, you should change your design and that logic somewhere outside of xml config

Comment: Of course I can call a static method from an instance, I am way more expert in Java than this level. I haven't spent so much time in couple of comments aimed at clarifying this point from the general point of view, your answer about the post processor is pretty useful anyway and I'm thankful for that.

Comment: sorry I didn't get your answer about instantiating IOUtils despite its private constructor. I came back to this today, tried the method and it works, thank you!